# How to add any html element in Material 2 Snack bar

Tags: angular, angular-material2, snackbar

My requirement is to show spinner inside Material 2 Snack bar.

In our application we are using Snack bar to show loading, success and error messages. With loading message I want to display spinner as well. I tried to add loader div inside snack bar but it is rendering as a text not as HTML element.

I tried to add with CSS class but it is getting applied to whole snack bar element.

I think if we able to insert another html element inside snack bar then we can able to show loader along with message.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of spinner are you looking to use?

I would take a look at [Angular-Busy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-busy), I have used it before and it's pretty promising. As for inner html, I don't know how easy that is to add inner HTML elements. I think it's main purpose is to show a tad bit of information. Maybe you should consider using a bootstrap alert and just hide it until you have an error or warning message.

Unfortunately Material's Angular documentation is terrible to say the least.

Here is an example that you can use for a spinner inside of a Toast notification
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weyJVP

`<div id="demo-toast-example" class="mdl-js-snackbar mdl-snackbar">
      <div class="mdl-spinner mdl-spinner--single-color mdl-js-spinner is-active"></div>
      <div class="mdl-snackbar__text"></div>
<button class="mdl-snackbar__action" type="button"></button>`

I bet you could just set a observable or boolean to the is-active value on the spinner in angular.

Best of luck.

Comment: The OP is talking about **angular-material2** and NOT **mdl**!

Comment: Yes I know, but the documentation for angular-material2 is terrible and you can use mdl as a standin